# Синонимы меток 2.0

Tags: обсуждение, синонимы-меток

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Январский брейншторм команды в результате привёл к переделке страницы синонимов меток. Встречайте [«Синонимы меток 2.0»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329687/260198)

Было так:

> [image: Синонимы меток 1.0]

Стало так:

> [image: Синонимы меток 2.0]

- Поменяли местами столбцы «синоним» и «цель», теперь удобно читать таблицу слева направо.
- Вместо вложенных вкладок теперь сортируемая таблица.
- Спец кнопка для модераторов.

Также добавлен способ голосования по синонимам непосредственно на вкладке «Ожидают утверждения»:

> [image: Ожидающие утверждения метки]

[@Адам](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear) всё ещё работает над некоторыми другими аспектами страницы (например, над созданием модальных окон для слияния тегов и создания синонимов). Кроме того, есть некоторый технический долг, который необходимо погасить, прежде чем другие функции будут развёрнуты.

Делимся мнениями и идеями по поводу новой странички.

Comment: Адаптивного дизайна всё равно не хватает.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ может ещё будет. Адам ещё не закончил с этим.

Comment: Ну, я не знаю, как там будет таблица на новые строки переноситься. Так что сомнительно вообще всё это.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ `будет таблица на новые строки переноситься` — а должна?

Comment: @ߊߚߤߘ если нет, то не понятно о каком адаптивном дизайне может идти речь. Всё будет мелко, што пепец, если уложить имеющуюся таблицу в ширину экрана телефона без какого-либо переноса.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Фи, телефон... [Большой должности — большой экран](https://hsto.org/files/2b4/55e/420/2b455e4208684f809904488ce88f0f1a.jpeg).

Comment: @ߊߚߤߘ ну, если оно складывается в карман, то можно и такой вариант. Что-то вспомнилась такая матрица на ["Гранд-макет Россия"](https://grandmaket.ru/).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Видео на главной заинтриговало (но будь это трансляцией, а не коротким отрывком — было бы ещё залипательнее). Наду будет туда сходить.

Comment: edem, верни смайлик! (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: @andreymal нельзя, на мете нужно быть серьёзным!

Comment: @ߊߚߤߘ [хех](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBn8n.png)